# Create a design matrix with levels in training set and not test set

Tags: r, matrix, model.matrix

I would like to create a design matrix from a test set using variable names from the training set.

For example, if my training set was

```
  (Intercept) Time2008 Time2009 Time2012   Rate Monocot1 Warm1
1           1        0        1        0   62.5        0     1
2           1        0        0        0  250.0        0     1
3           1        0        0        0 1000.0        0     1
4           1        0        0        0 1000.0        0     1
5           1        0        0        0   62.5        0     1
6           1        0        0        0 1000.0        0     1
```

And my test data was

```
  Time      Rate Monocot Warm
1 2012   1.00000       0    1
2 2012  35.44828       0    1
3 2012  69.89655       0    1
4 2012 104.34483       0    1
5 2012 138.79310       0    1
6 2012 173.24138       0    1
```

which only has 2012 as a level for time, then I would like in the design matrix for my test data to have columns for the levels that are in the training data with zeros indicating their absence. model.matrix does not allow me to do this.

Also, model.matrix will not let me put a column of ones for a factor with one level, 2012. However I would still like this in the design matrix for the test set along with other columns with zeros. Thank you in advance.

Comment: So you aren't training on any data that has 2012 but you want to still make predictions for that value? And you are treating that variable as categorical? That doesn't seem statistically possible. Unless you maybe want to treat year as a continuous numeric random variable, you generally can't predict on values you never observed for discrete variables.

Comment: Thank you for that. I have changed it so that this variable would appear in training set.

Comment: `test$time = factor(test$time, levels = levels(train$time))`. Make sure `train$time` is a factor first.

Comment: Thank you sir. Problem solved.